# Uncheck check box some other action

Tags: jquery

I know it may look wierd but everything works fine except the bit where iam tryin to grab the id and attach it to the [name=checkme]

How do i go about formatting that line so that the id will be recoginsed.

```
$('input:checkbox[name=checkme'+id+']').attr('checked',"");
```

It wont work as is but if i remove the +id it works and unchecks all checkboxes.

Hope that makes sense :)

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">    

    function deleterow(id) {

    var txt = $.ajax({

    (do stuff here)     

    }).success


    $('input:checkbox[name=checkme'+id+']').attr('checked',"");  

    }

    </script>
```

Comment: `id:+id` why this? Can you post html?

Comment: id:+id is related to the ajax post, its processed by the process.php file thats used to remove a mysql row. Its not my problem, its just the format of the single line in the success result thats giving me grief. :)

Comment: But your success is not properly formatted. `}).success;`???

Comment: everything works fine except i dont know hot to include my id into the [name=checkme]+id etc... ?? not sure of that bit.

Comment: You may say everything works, but there is still several syntax-errors in this code which might result in your error...

Comment: i have re adjusted my post to be clearer. I have firebug and can see if an error occurs across many browsers. This is more about formatting one line. IF you say i hgave syntax errors then please oblige by providing the correct format. I know from experiencethat there are several ways to write a jquery block like mine. So unless you provide some more info then im not sure how you can help?

Comment: what is the html for your checkboxes?

Comment: ps: thtas exactly why im asking the question, its related to the one line that is causing me syntax issues. The rest of my code snippet works just fine across many major browsers.

Comment: @rahul <input name="checkme<?php echo $id; ?>" ... >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox[name="checkme' + id + '"]').attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select an element that has a name attribute like `checkme1` where the `1` is in the variable `id` then what you already have should work:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="checkme'+id+'"]').attr('checked',"");
```

If you are trying to select an element with an id attribute that is in your `id` variable then this should work:

```
$('#' + id).attr('checked',"");
```

If that doesn't work please post the html for the checkbox(es) in question so that I can see what you're talking about.

Note that to uncheck a checkbox you should say `.prop("checked", false);` rather than using `attr()` (unless you are on a version of jQuery before 1.6).

Comment: cool thankyou nnnnnnn , the false part is great heads up. I will fix that. the first note youmade wont work for me though?

Comment: Look at this recent solved question it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237253/how-to-get-a-part-of-id-element-using-jquery

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the code you had didn't put quotes around the attribute value in the selector so I've updated my answer to do that. (I.e., `[name="..."]` rather than `[name=...]`.) If that still doesn't work please use your browser's "View Source" option to double-check exactly what is output from your PHP code.

Comment: @elclanrs thankyou, but i got it with some formatting suggestions.