# How to get a part of id element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How I can get a "Some text" from span with id="old-[id]" and put it in id="new-[id]" ?

```
<span id="old-1">Some text</span>
<span id="new-1"></span>
<span id="old-5">Some text</span>
<span id="new-5"></span>
```

I don't know how to get a digital part of `id` without `substring()` function. 
I think exists is more correct solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `substring()`?

Comment: I think it makes the code less flexible for future modifications of html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your question is not entirely clear what you're asking, I'll offer you a bunch of different examples:

For a single id, you could do this:

```
$("#new-1").text($("#old-1").text());
```

If you have a bunch of sequential IDs that you want to do this on, you could do this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $("#new-" + i).text($("#old-" + i).text());
}
```

If it's HTML, not just text, you can use .html() in place of .text() in the above code.

```
$("#new-1").html($("#old-1").html());
```

or

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $("#new-" + i).html($("#old-" + i).html());
}
```

If you want to find all objects that have IDs that start with "old-" and process all of them regardless of how many and what numbers are on them, you could do this:

```
$('[id^="old-"]').each(function() {
    var newid = this.id.replace(/old/, "new");
    $("#" + newid).html($(this).html())
})
```

This will create a jQuery object of all objects that have an id that starts with "old-" and then replace the "old" with "new" to create the destination id value and use that to copy the HTML from the source to the destination.

If you have a given object in a variable named `elem` and you want to extract just the numeric portion of the id value, you can use a regular expresssion to match the numeric portion like this:

```
var matches = elem.id.match(/\d+$/);
if (matches) {
    var numString = matches[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. The penultimate example is what I need. Also the last example is great.

Comment: This "$('[id^="old-"]')" is what I needed to loop through tabs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to retrieve an id **without knowing it before-hand** so that you can duplicate the text of that element.

If that's correct, this short jQuery function will do so.

```
$('span').each(function()
    {
        var idnum = $(this).attr('id').match(/[\d]/);
        $('#new-' + idnum).text($(this).text());
    }
);
```

I have created [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/cRxpM/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contents of *all* of the `old-n` spans to be copied to the corresponding `new-n` spans then this should do it:

```
$('span[id^="old-"]').each(function() {
   $('#new-' + this.id.split('-')[1]).html( $(this).html() );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/bcXFf/

(Normally I would use `.substr()` to do this since you already know the position within the string where the number occurs, but since you've asked to avoid it I've used `.split()` instead.)

`^=` is the ["attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), so the above code selects all spans with an `id` that starts with "old-" and then for each one it finds the corresponding "new-" span and copies the content into it.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
var id = 1;
$('#new-'+id).text($('#old-'+id).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript paseInt() function will return only the integer part of a mixed string/integer variable. If you store the value of $('#old-1).attr('id') in a variable then parseInt on it, it should return just the number.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var el = $("#old-1");
    var oldId = el.attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, "");
    $("#new-" + oldId).text(el.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var spanText = $('#old-1').text();
    $('#old-1').text(null);
    $('#new-1').text(spanText);
});
```

That will take the text from old and put it in new. 
If you have to do it will multiple id's then you will just have to write a loop to go through it or use the $.each method to iterate through all the id's.